# Diminuir o número de barras do gráfico BarChart chart js

Tags: chartjs

Como posso diminuir o número de barras a serem exibidas de acordo com o mês que estamos?

Ec: atualmente nosso mês é 11 (Nov), desta forma, gostaria que fossem apresentadas apenas as 10 primeiras colunas do gráfico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Antes de montar o gráfico, você tem que pensar em como e o que irá mostrar, pois um gráfico é baseado em valores, ou seja, é uma representação visual de valores passados pelo usuário, dados provenientes de *request HTTP*, ou mesmo um arquivo *JSON*.

Você obtendo os dados, a primeira coisa que deve fazer é, manipulá-los para que estejam na forma que você quer apresentar no gráfico. Exemplo:

- Se você tem dados que representam um período de 24 horas, mas apenas quer mostrar das 13:00 às 17:00. Você deve filtrar esses dados do objeto original, gerar um novo objeto com os dados que você quer e posteriormente passar para o gráfico, assim mostrando apenas o que você quer.
- Seguindo o raciocínio da sua pergunta, se você quer apresentar apenas os 10 primeiros meses, com base no mês atual (11), você deve então filtrar o objeto/array original e pegar apenas os dados dos 10 primeiros meses e posteriormente passar para o gráfico. Pois não faz sentido fazer esses filtros no próprio gráfico, a não ser que queira interação com o usuário, fazendo com que ele possa ver o mês 11, clicando em algum botão, por exemplo.

Concluindo, monte primeiro toda sua estratégia, desde como será o gráfico, o tipo dele, como ele será visualizado e posteriormente você pegará os dados, irá filtra-los e então passar para o gráfico.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz algo parecido no highcharts. basta você colocar uma função que vai atuar como manipulador dos dados antes de serem entregues ao charts.

Aí nesta função vc verifica o mês e usa a regra que deseja.

algo do tipo

var dados = function(array){

```
var ret = [];

var mes = new Date().getMonth();  // janeiro é 0

for(var k in array){

   if(k < mes){

        ret.push(array[k]);

    }

}

return ret;
```

}(array);

deste jeito vc faz um filtro, e como janeiro é 0, novembro é 10, e a variável k percorrerá seu array q supondo que é 1 para cada mês ele vai de 0 a 11. logo a condição k < mes serve perfeitamente.

espero ter ajudado um pouco